# How to find lowest index of min number in array java?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, minimum

Except 0, how to find a min. number in array :

```
myMethod()
{
    for (i - 0 to i - length)
    {
        int currentMin = value_at_first_Index;
        if(currentMin > value_at_first_Index)
            currentMin = value_at_first_Index;
    }
    return currentMin;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Correct solution:

```
int FindFirstMinIndex(array)
{
    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<array.length; i++)
        if(array.elementAt(i) < array.elementAt(minIndex))
            minIndex=i;
    return minIndex;
}
```

### How it works:

1. Start with the assumption that the first element (index `0`) is the minimum:

   - `int minIndex = 0;`
2. Loop from the second element through the rest of the array:

   - `for (int i = 1; i<array.length; i++)`
   - Start from the second (index `1`) element instead of the first (index `0`) because we already assume the first will be the minimum if we find nothing with a lower value, and there is no need to compare it with itself inside the loop.
3. If the value of the element at the loop's current index (`i`) is less than the value of the element at the recorded minimum's index so far:

   - `if(array.elementAt(i) < array.elementAt(minIndex))`
4. Then a new minimum value has been found. Assign it's index as the new minimum's index:

   - `minIndex=i;`
5. After the loop, whatever index is recorded to the `minIndex` variable, is guaranteed to be the first index (in case of duplicate values) of the minimum value found throughout the array. So return that index:

   - `return minIndex;`

Answer (score 1):

```
    int a[]={5,2,4,5,1,7,9};
    int lowestIndex=0;
    for(int b=1; b<7; b++)
    {
        if(a[b]<a[lowestIndex]) lowestIndex=b;
    }
    return lowestIndex;
```

Comment: Slight error in the *descriptiveness* of the `lowestIndex` variable. The *lowest index* would always be `0`. A more correct description for the variable would be *minimum's index*; so a more correct name for the variable would be `minIndex`, as in my answer. --- Other than that, this is the only answer that is both correct and rreadable (other than my own) so far...

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
public int getMin (int[] arr) { int currentMin = arr[0]; for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ if (arr[i] != 0){ currentMin = Math.min(arr[i], currentMin); }}return currentMin; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Move currentMin out of the for loop

```
 public int myMethod (int[] array) {
    int currentMin = array[0]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] != 0 && array[i]>currentMin)
               currentMin=array[i];
                    }
    return currentMin;
}
```